# How do you loop through several objects to find, for example, a name?

Tags: java, loops, object, methods

I have created 4 objects of the class "Testklasse". Each of these objects have a name (Ingrid, Ask, Tom, Dana) and they each represent a person. What I am trying to do is create different methods that loop through the objects to see if they know each other, are bf/gf, if they like each other etc. etc. I have tried to create the method blirKjentMed (trans.: getsToKnow), but it isn't working and I don't know where to go from here. 
Any tips?

```
import easyIO.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

    class Oblig1{
        public static void main(String[] args){
        Testklasse t = new Testklasse();

        }

    }
    class Testklasse{

        public Testklasse(){

            Person ingrid = new Person("Ingrid", 3);
            Person ask = new Person("Ask", 3);
            Person tom = new Person("Tom", 3);
            Person dana = new Person("Dana",3);

            ingrid.blirKjentMed(ingrid);
        }
    }

    class Person{

        private String navn; 
        private Person [] kjenner;
        private Person [] kjennerIkke; 
        private Person forelsket;
        private Person sammenmed;

        Person(String n, int lengde){
            this.navn = n;
            this.kjenner = new Person[lengde];
            this.kjennerIkke = new Person[lengde];
            this.forelsket = forelsket;
            this.sammenmed = sammenmed;


        }

        public void blirKjentMed(Person ingrid){
            for(int i = 0; i < ingrid.kjenner.length; i++){
                if(ingrid.navn.equalsIgnoreCase("ingrid")){
                    continue;
                } else {
                    kjenner[i] = ingrid;
                    System.out.println(ingrid.navn + kjenner[i].navn);
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Well right now your arrays are empty. Not sure what you are really trying to do in your getsToKnow method. Right now since you pass ingrid to itself, you probably observed that it essentially does nothing. If you pass, say, tom to ingrid, it will do something (fill ingrid's array with tom) but I'm not sure what it's supposed to accomplish. If you could clarify your description a bit so it's more specific about what you are trying to do maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Put your objects into an array or an `ArrayList`, and then inter ate through it:

```
for(Testklasse obj : myArray) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a homework problem, because a fixed-size array is not an appropriate representation of a person's friends. People can have many friends, and the list can change.

Let's look at the `Person` class.  As you will have noticed, the constructor does not quite work because it constructs a `Perspn` with `null` for `forelsket` and `sammenmed`.  The line

```
this.forelsket = forelsket;  \\ Google: forelsket means lover in English.
```

does not work.  `forelsket` is never initialized, so at the beginning of the constructor, `this.forelsket` is `null`. Since `forelsket` does not appear as a constructor argument, the code snippet is interpreted as

```
this.forelsket = this.forelsket;
```

which does nothing.  A better constructor would be:

```
Person(final String n,         final Person forelsket,
       final Person sammenmed, final int    lengde) {
    this.navn        = n;
    this.forelsket   = forelsket;
    this.sammenmed   = sammenmed;
    this.kjenner     = new Person[lengde];
    this.kjennerIkke = new Person[lengde];
}
```

though getting rid of `lengde` and using `ArrayList` would be better once you learn about collections.

Next, you need to write methods to manipulate the `kjenner` and `kjennerIkke` arrays (or lists).  You can fill these in yourself:

```
public void  setForelsket(final Person forelsket);
public Person getForelsket();
public void  setSammenmed(final Person sammenmed);
public Person getSammenmed();
// Return whether the addition changed anything.
public boolean addKjenner(Person kjenner);
public boolean removeKjenner(Person kjenner);
// Same for kjennerIkke.
```

And after all that, you probably want to create your own `equals` and `hashCode` methods; these are necessary for collections.